# QT Creator Error (no match for operator+)

Tags: c++, qt, stack, match, operator-keyword

I'm attempting to build a Reverse Polish Notation calculator in QT Creator 5.6.0. However, every time I build my code I receive the following error:

> no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'double' and 'QCharRef')

Below is the snippet of the code where the problem is happening. (I've used the 4 asterisks to mark the line where the error is happening)

```
double MainWindow::runCalculation(QString correctPostfix)
{
QStack<double> postfixStack;

for(int i = 0;i< correctPostfix.length();i++) {

    if(correctPostfix[i] == ' ' || correctPostfix[i] == ',') continue;

    else if(isOperator(correctPostfix[i])) {
        double val2 = postfixStack.top(); postfixStack.pop();
        double val1 = postfixStack.top(); postfixStack.pop();
        double result = performOp(correctPostfix[i], val1, val2);
        postfixStack.push(result);
    }
    else if(isOperand(correctPostfix[i])){
        double operand = 0;
        while(i<correctPostfix.length() && isOperand(correctPostfix[i])) {
 ****          operand = operand + (correctPostfix[i]);
            i++;
        }
        i--;

        postfixStack.push(operand);
    }
}
```

The code was working perfectly fine before I tried moving it into QT. Below is the code I was using for this function when it was run in the console.

```
double calculate(string correctPostfix)
{
            stack<double> postfixStack;

for(int i = 0;i< correctPostfix.length();i++) {

    if(correctPostfix[i] == ' ' || correctPostfix[i] == ',') continue; 

    else if(isOperator(correctPostfix[i])) {
        double val2 = postfixStack.top(); postfixStack.pop();
        double val1 = postfixStack.top(); postfixStack.pop();
        double result = performOp(correctPostfix[i], val1, val2);
        postfixStack.push(result);
    }
    else if(isOperand(correctPostfix[i])){
        double operand = 0; 
        while(i<correctPostfix.length() && isOperand(correctPostfix[i])) {
            operand = (operand*10) + (correctPostfix[i] - '0'); 
            i++;
        }
        i--;

        postfixStack.push(operand);
    }
}

return postfixStack.top();
}
```

Comment: But code is not the same and currently you're adding a double with...QCharRef...which result you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> operand = operand + (correctPostfix[i]);

make like this

```
QString currentPostfixStr(correctPostfix[i]);
operand = operand + currentPostfixStr.toDouble();
```

And this make QString

> double calculate(string correctPostfix)

what does you mean thih code:

> correctPostfix[i] - '0'

Comment: Ah thank you very much! Sorry for any of the confusing or sloppy code, I've only been using c++ for a couple of months. Thank you very much for the help!